# Tensorflow's Custom Loss functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function, image-recognition

I was doing a recognition task and found that Deep Metric based Learning can play a crucial role in the training process. I saw loss functions like arcface, cosface, and many more loss functions. In Their TensorFlow implementation, these loss functions were implemented like last a layer in a model and during the compilation of that model some other loss function is used like Sparse Categorical Crossentropy loss in this case.

```py
class ArcMarginProduct(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, n_classes, s=30, m=0.50, easy_margin=False,
                 ls_eps=0.0, **kwargs):

        super(ArcMarginProduct, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.s = s
        self.m = m
        self.ls_eps = ls_eps
        self.easy_margin = easy_margin
        self.cos_m = tf.math.cos(m)
        self.sin_m = tf.math.sin(m)
        self.th = tf.math.cos(math.pi - m)
        self.mm = tf.math.sin(math.pi - m) * m

    def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'n_classes': self.n_classes,
            's': self.s,
            'm': self.m,
            'ls_eps': self.ls_eps,
            'easy_margin': self.easy_margin,
        })
        return config

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(ArcMarginProduct, self).build(input_shape[0])

        self.W = self.add_weight(
            name='W',
            shape=(int(input_shape[0][-1]), self.n_classes),
            initializer='glorot_uniform',
            dtype='float32',
            trainable=True,
            regularizer=None)

    def call(self, inputs):
        X, y = inputs
            y = tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.int32)
            cosine = tf.matmul(
                tf.math.l2_normalize(X, axis=1),
                tf.math.l2_normalize(self.W, axis=0)
            )
            sine = tf.math.sqrt(1.0 - tf.math.pow(cosine, 2))
            phi = cosine * self.cos_m - sine * self.sin_m
            if self.easy_margin:
                phi = tf.where(cosine > 0, phi, cosine)
            else:
                phi = tf.where(cosine > self.th, phi, cosine - self.mm)
            one_hot = tf.cast(
                tf.one_hot(y, depth=self.n_classes),
                dtype=cosine.dtype
            )
            if self.ls_eps > 0:
                one_hot = (1 - self.ls_eps) * one_hot + self.ls_eps / self.n_classes
    
            output = (one_hot * phi) + ((1.0 - one_hot) * cosine)
            output *= self.s
            return output
    
        E

    FNS = [efn.EfficientNetB0, efn.EfficientNetB1, efn.EfficientNetB2, efn.EfficientNetB3, 
                    efn.EfficientNetB4, efn.EfficientNetB5, efn.EfficientNetB6, efn.EfficientNetB7]
        
        def freeze_BN(model):
            # Unfreeze layers while leaving BatchNorm layers frozen
            for layer in model.layers:
                if not isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
                    layer.trainable = True
                else:
                    layer.trainable = False
        
        # Function to create our EfficientNetB3 model
        def get_model():
    
        with strategy.scope():
    
            margin = ArcMarginProduct(
                n_classes = N_CLASSES, 
                s = 30, 
                m = 0.5, 
                name='head/arc_margin', 
                dtype='float32'
                )
    
            inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (*IMAGE_SIZE, 3), name = 'inp1')
            label = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (), name = 'inp2')
            x = EFNS[EFF_NET](weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)(inp)
            x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
            x = margin([x, label])
            
            output = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(dtype='float32')(x)
    
            model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [inp, label], outputs = [output])
    
            opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = LR)
            if FREEZE_BATCH_NORM:
                freeze_BN(model)
    
            model.compile(
                optimizer = opt,
                loss = [tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()],
                metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
                ) 
            
            return model
    get_model().summary()
```

Other than layer like the implementation of loss functions I found another implementation that is based on TensorFlow custom loss functions

```py
class ArcFaceLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss) :
    # m:margin
    # s:magnification
    # loss_func:Original loss function tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True)Such
    def __init__(self, loss_func, m = 0.5, s = 30, name = "arcface_loss", **kwargs) :
        self.loss_func = loss_func
        self.margin = m
        self.s = s
        self.enable = True
        super(ArcFaceLoss, self).__init__(name = name, **kwargs)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # y_pred is cos(θ)
        #Sin for the addition theorem(θ)To calculate
        sine = tf.keras.backend.sqrt(1.0 - tf.keras.backend.square(y_pred))
        phi = y_pred * self.cos_m - sine * self.sin_m       # cos(θ+m)Addition theorem
        phi = tf.where(y_pred > 0, phi, y_pred)             #As it is when facing the day after tomorrow

        #Correct answer class:cos(θ+m)Other classes:cosθ 
        logits = (y_true * phi) + ((1.0 - y_true) * y_pred)

        #Call the original loss function
        return self.loss_func(y_true, logits * self.s)

#Evaluation function for ArcFace
class ArcFaceAccuracy(tf.keras.metrics.Mean) :
    def __init__(self, metrics_func, s = 30, name = "arcface_accuracy", dtype = None) :
        self.metrics_func = metrics_func
        self.s = s
        super(ArcFaceAccuracy, self).__init__(name, dtype)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None) :
        output = tf.nn.softmax(y_pred * self.s)
        matches = self.metrics_func(y_true, output)

        return super(ArcFaceAccuracy, self).update_state(matches, sample_weight = sample_weight)
```

Now I am confused which implementation is correct, if both of them are correct implementations then why are we using loss function as a layer in the model and which implementation is efficient to use while working with big data